# Hide the button and show again on touch

Tags: android, touch, hide, visible, invisible

I am working on an application where I want to hide the button, or, say, make the button ***invisible*** when I touch the screen and again make the button ***visible*** when I again touch the screen.

How I can make it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement an onTouchListener

```
 // Catch touch events here
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        System.out.println("Touch Down X:" + event.getX() + " Y:" + event.getY());
    } 
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        System.out.println("Touch Up X:" + event.getX() + " Y:" + event.getY());
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Then in this you'll want to reference the button and set it's visibility:

```
  button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); or View.INVISIBLE
```

Comment: `View.GONE` might also be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might solve your problem.

```
    LinearLayout mainLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lLay);
    int flagForButton = 0;
    Button b1 = new Button(this);
    b1.setVisibility(0);

    mainLay .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouch Listener)
    {
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action==0)
            {
            }
            else
                if (action == 1)
                {
                    if (flagForButton ==1)
                    {
                        b1.setVisibility(0);
                        flagForButton = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        b1.setVisibility(4);
                        flagForButton = 1;
                    }
                }
        }
    });
```